# Loop over query result in postgresql without using a predefined table

Tags: postgresql, loops

I've created a function to loop over query results and it works fine. I'd like to have it work without my having to pre-create a table to store the results. Ie, I just want to iterate over the rows. Thing is, I'm not sure how to declare a record that is the same type as the rows returned when there is nothing to check against.

Here is my current function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dimensions.testing()
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $body$
DECLARE rec myschema.tmpfiles%rowtype;
BEGIN

insert into myschema.tmpfiles(file_name, log_date)  
    SELECT f.file_name, f.log_date from dblink('conn', 'select 
file_name, log_date from myschema.process_tracker where 
isprocessed = FALSE') as f(file_name varchar, log_date date);

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myschema.tmpfiles) THEN
    for rec in select * from myschema.tmpfiles
loop
        RAISE NOTICE '%', rec.file_name;
        RAISE NOTICE '%', rec.log_date;
        RAISE NOTICE '---------------------------';
end loop;           
ELSE
    --DO SOMETHING
END IF;

END;
$body$
```

Works fine, but it needs a predefined table in order for me to do this: (DECLARE rec myschema.tmpfiles%rowtype;) and get the row type.

How to loop over this query without pre-defining the result table?

Thanks!

Comment: `declare rec record`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RECORD type is a row-type variable with no predefined structure.

You declare it by doing `name RECORD;`

> Record variables are similar to row-type variables, but they have no
>   predefined structure. They take on the actual row structure of the row
>   they are assigned during a SELECT or FOR command. The substructure of
>   a record variable can change each time it is assigned to. A
>   consequence of this is that until a record variable is first assigned
>   to, it has no substructure, and any attempt to access a field in it
>   will draw a run-time error.

Change `myschema.tmpfiles%rowtype` to `RECORD` and you should be fine.